# What's the cause of Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression::whereRaw()?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, query-builder

I'm trying to perform a query where I need to count `isApprove` column with a value of 1 in my `approvals_document`. Here how I did it in the SQL query.

```
SELECT documents.id, documents.isApprove,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM approvals_document WHERE approvals_document.isApprove = 1 and approvals_document.document_id = documents.id) as approvedBy
FROM documents;
```

Output:

```
id | isApprove | approvedBy
96      0            3
```

When I'm performing this in Laravel using `DB::raw` and `whereRaw` expression. It throws me a error.

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression::whereRaw()

Here how I performed it in Laravel way.

```
public function count()
{
  $count = DB::table('documents')
    ->select('documents.id', 'documents.isApprove', DB::raw('COUNT(FROM approvals_document) as approvedBy')
    ->whereRaw('approvals_document.isApprove = 1 and approvals_document.document_id = documents.id'))
    ->get();
    dd($count);
}
```

Any help how did I get this problem? Any help would appreciated!

Update: I followed aynber tips using left join but I got this error.

[image: SC]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your parenthesis mixed up. You need an extra one after your select, not after your whereRaw:

```
$count = DB::table('documents')
->leftJoin('approvals_document','documents.id','=','approvals_document.document_id')
->select('documents.id', 'documents.isApprove', DB::raw('COUNT(approvals_document.*) as approvedBy')) // Close your DB::raw and your select here
->whereRaw('approvals_document.isApprove = 1 and approvals_document.document_id = documents.id')
->get();
```

Comment: I got an error near 'FROM approvals_document) as approvedBy from `documents` where approvals_document' at line 1.

Comment: Remove the FROM, it's only used to select a table. I'll update the query with what it should be.

Comment: I also added the JOIN command, since it probably would not have connected the two tables together otherwise.

Comment: It still throws me a error near. `'*) as approvedBy` :(

Comment: I'm at a loss here. You can try id instead of *, and the join may be wrong... I'd suggest playing with the query inside of mysql to make sure you're getting the values you want, then converting it to laravel.

Comment: It's already working. I see my error. It doesn't connect this two table. Because what I did int sql I didn't join anything. Thanks for this. :D